# What's wrong with this code? I'm trying to change a label text with NSString and NSLog

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to do something very simple, I'm trying to change a label to "I like to say hi" by clicking a button. I already know how to do it without NSString but I wanted to make it more harder, but I can't find what's wrong with this code. It's not working.

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender{
    NSString *hi = @"hi";
    _label.text = NSLog(@"I like to say %@", hi);
}
```

I'm also trying to do something even more complicated and use a void statement like this. Would this work, and if not what's wrong with it?

```
- (void)num{
int num = 42;
}

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender{
    _label.text = NSLog(@"I like to say %i", num);
}
```

Comment: I politely suggest you go find a nice beginner's tutorial on the Objective-C programming language. You need to learn the basics before moving on any further. Good luck. SO is not the proper place to learn how to program.

Comment: like @rmaddy i will suggest you to learn some very basics of objective c. here is a [good link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) to start.   good luck

Comment: It might also be helpful to qualify "I can't find what's wrong with this code" with some actual error messages or context e.g doe it compile? Does it give a runtime error, and if so, what is that error, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to use `NSLog` for this? That's for showing messages in the log.

You want `NSString stringWithFormat:`.

```
_label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I like to say %@", hi);
```

What you have won't even compile since the `NSLog` function does not return an `NSString` value.

Answer (score 2):

`NSLog` is a function with a `void` return type, which means it does not return any value, so you can't use it to assign the value of a property. It is used only for printing messages to the debugging console or device logs. What you are probably looking for is `stringWithFormat:`

```
_label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I like to say %@", hi];
```

This is a method of the `NSString` class. It constructs strings similar to NSLog, but it actually returns a new NSString value that can be assigned to properties and so on.

[Read its documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_19). You will be using this and other NSString methods all the time.

---

Regarding your other code:

If you want to construct a method named `num` that produces a value you can use elsewhere, you need to declare the type of the value it returns, instead of using `void`:

```
- (int)num{
    return 42;
}
```

Now `num` is a proper *instance method*. You will need to tweak your code to be able to access this method correctly:

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender{
    _label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I like to say %i", [self num]];
}
```

Here you are *sending the message* `num` to `self`. The keyword `self` is, loosely speaking, a reference to the current object instance. So `[self num]` will invoke the `num` method you have defined, and return its value. You may want to read [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210) to learn more about these concepts.